# Hover on element and click for other element when visible in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent, newrelic

I have an asset container when hovered over it displays the other elements for Download and Detail view Icons. So now I am trying to use mouseMove() on the asset Container but still it does not display the other elements when hovered

```
.then(function() {
            log("Hover Asset detail");

            return $browser.waitForAndFindElement($driver.By.css("class element"), DefaultTimeout)
                .then(function(el) {
                    $browser.actions().mouseMove(el).perform()
                    return 
                });
        })`
```

Comment: What is the exception stack trace ?

Comment: When I hover over that class element , there are other two elements visible when hovered. I want to click on one of that element after hovering.So in my above code when I do mouseMove for the element it's not displaying the elements on hover.

Comment: Can anyone please help with a solution. I am still having the problem to hover on element and click the other element being visible when hovered